# How can I generate and compile Java files in Android at Runtime

Tags: java, android, javac, dsl, dynamically-generated

I know with javax.tools.* it is possible, but since this is not included in the Android API, I'm desperately wondering, is this possible?

Right now, my goal is to create a drag-and-drop tool to allow users to create their own layouts (as not everyone wants to learn Mobile Development, as it requires a lot of time, dedication and practice) similar to how Android Studio does it's own. However, of course the most important thing is to implement functionality via onClickListener and onTouchListeners. I've begun remedying this by creating my own DSL (Domain-Specific-Language) with a GUI front-end allowing users to choose what they want via PopupMenu and SubMenus. For example...

**Statements**

{ if, for, while }

Statements must be followed immediately by a reference and then a conditional (obtained from that reference), like a "if(Object.conditional())" statement.

**References**

{ Object1, Object2, Object3 }

The objects are references to other Views (I.E, Buttons, Layouts, WebView, etc.).

**Conditionals|Actions|Getters|Setters**

{ isSomething(), doSomething(), getSomething(), setSomething() }

Each Reference's methods, wrapped so that each wrapper keeps track of it's method's attributes and description (hence documentation).

It would go something like such...

```
IF ImageView1.isVisible()
    ImageView1.setVisible(false)
ELSE
    ImageView1.setVisible(true)
```

Of course, the method setVisible(boolean) is a wrapped version of setVisiblity(int).None of this is typed, it is obtained from a simple PopupMenu which shows them the applicable selections based on current context.

How I plan on transcribing this to compiling code was to convert the statement into Java code, inserting references on the fly as they are needed (I.E, ImageView1 would be defined in java as private ImageView ImageView1;), generate methods somewhat similar to how ButterKnife generates it's extra classes for it's onClick and onTouch annotations, etc.

Then, after planning all of this (been working on it for 2 weeks now), I find out that Android does not have support for compiling code like this. Please tell me something like this is possible. It's something I 100% wanted to do. Is this possible with any third party libraries?

If not, is there some possible way to mimic doing so? I could do it the long and slow way, of preparing every such possible way, keeping track of the references myself through a map, and when it is about to be called, directly call the implemented method for the View associated with that key, which theoretically COULD work. In fact, that'd be my second go-to if I can't. It'd be messy though.
Sorry if this is too long, I just want to get this to work.

**TL;DR:** Is there a way to compile a generated Java file created at Runtime in Android (since javax.tools.* does not exist), and if not what would be the best way to do so?

Comment: "Is there a way to compile a generated Java file created at Runtime in Android" -- not in the Android SDK.

Comment: Is there a third party library that can do something like this? I see something like "https://github.com/crittercism/dexmaker", but I don't know if this would actually work.

Comment: Why does it have to actually compile Java code if your user isn't even entering Java code? You seem to have chosen the most complicated approach possible.

Comment: Beyond Xaver's comment, I wouldn't do what you are describing, from a security standpoint.

Comment: The end-goal is that I want to generate both .xml and .java files that can be ran both dynamically at Runtime, and also in an IDE. Hence, it would be possible go backwards (run both .java and .xml created in an IDE dynamically at Runtime).

Comment: @CommonsWare What security issues would arise from this?

Comment: If the user exploits something, they are only harming themselves, right?

Comment: Runtime code hot-loading is a vector for code-injection attacks.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the terms. What would be the worst case scenario for this?

Comment: Also I've another question, if I compile it to Java code, isn't there the efficiency boost of the ART? I am reconsidering compiling to Java code, however maybe it's because my plans for this is too ambitious and possibly impossible. I also wanted to, if people liked using it, add possibility to create their own Functions, Classes (and Objects), Inheritence, Polymorphism, Data Structures, etc. into my DSL. Perhaps I'm thinking too far ahead, though, but I'm not sure how all of this would be possible otherwise.